# How can I retain a template selected using ajax in dropdown of grails even after refreshing the browser?

Tags: ajax, grails, dropdown

I have a dropdown in grails with multiple options. On each option selected in dropdown , the particular template is loaded via AJAX . So, when I refresh the page the I managed to keep the dropdown value as it was but the template is not retained.

**In gsp:**

```
<div class="pull-right " id="categorydropdown">
    <g:select class="selectpicker text-center" name="sortByCategories" id="sortByCategories" from="${sortByCategories}" optionKey="value" optionValue="value" value="A" onchange="getcategories()"/>
</div>

<div id="loadedtemplate"></div>
```

**In js:**

```
function getcategories(){
var selectedValue = $('#sortByCategories').val();
var contentdiv = $('#loadedtemplate');
$('#loading-gif').show();

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: htps://localhost:8080/project/getDropdownCategories',
    data: 'selectedValue='+selectedValue',
    success: function(data){
        $(contentdiv).html(data).fadeIn('fast');
        $('#loading-gif').hide();
    }
    }).error(function(){
        $('#loading-gif').hide();
    });
}
```

**In controller:**

```
def getDropdownCategories() {
    def list= projectService.getList(params.selectedValue)

    def model = [list: list]

    if (request.xhr) {
        if (params.selectedValue == 'A') {
            render(template: "/project/listA", model: model)
        }
        else if(params.selectedValue=='B'){
            render(template: "/project/listB", model: model)
            } 

        }else if(params.selectedValue=='C'){
            render(template: "/project/listC", model: model)
            }
        else if(params.selectedValue=='D'){
            render(template: "/project/listD", model: model)
            }  

    }
}
```

Comment: could you show us the code you use?

Comment: @IvoBorer I have added the code.